# sql sum using one to many relations

Tags: mysql, sum, one-to-many

i have two tables

```
comments
------------------
id       text

rates
---------------------
id    comment_id    score
```

My query is ... but sum operation not affected. just one row will be returen.

```
SELECT *, SUM(rates.score) FROM comment LEFT JOIN rate ON (rate.comment_id = comment.id)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT comment.*, SUM(rates.score) FROM comment LEFT JOIN rate ON (rate.comment_id = comment.id)
GROUP BY comment.id
```

Answer (score 4):

Your current query will simply sum the ratings of ALL comments. What you must do is incorporate `GROUP BY` which will group the aggregation by ***each*** comment, and so the result of the `SUM()` will ***only*** be the sum of ratings for each particular comment:

```
SELECT a.*, SUM(b.score) AS ratingsum
FROM comment a
LEFT JOIN rate b ON a.id = b.comment_id
GROUP BY a.id
```

Answer (score 2):

Try adding a group by clause:

```
 SELECT comment.*, SUM(rates.score) FROM comment LEFT JOIN rate ON rate.comment_id = comment.id GROUP BY rates.comment_id;
```